# Java thread/process with retry and failover

Tags: java, multithreading, rpc

I'm looking to implement a mechnism in Java in which I spawn a task.  What the task does is actually not relevant here and it can be done via a thread or new process.

What I really need is this:

- The task can be set to retry N times
- If something nasty happens within the tasks, the parent that spawned it is protected
- Both of the above should be abstracted away from me

Does anyone know of any frameworks that would do that in Java?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html). They do all that for you. Perhaps a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).

Comment: I think Akka will solve this.  Happy to answer my own question if someone can confirm?

Answer (score 2):

I've been thinking about this for quite a while now and finally got something you might consider useful.

First part of our little "framework" is the `Task` interface:

```
public interface Task {
    void work();
    void stop();
}
```

Implementing this we can set up our `WorkTask`:

```
public class WorkTask implements Task {
    @Override
    public void work() {
        // Do something useful...
        // might throw SomethingNastyHappenedException
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // implement as needed e.g. to break inner loops
    }

}
```

To comply with your requirement to be able to retry this we create a `Wrapper` class:

```
public class RetryingTaskWrapper implements Task {
    private Task wrappedTask;
    private int maxTries;
    private boolean running = false;

    public RetryingTaskWrapper(Task wrappedTask, int maxTries) {
        this.wrappedTask = wrappedTask;
        this.maxTries = maxTries;
    }

    @Override
    public void work() {
        running = true;
        boolean success = false;
        int tries = 0;

        while (running && !success && tries < maxTries) {
            try {
                wrappedTask.work();
                success = true;
            } catch (SomethingNastyHappenedException e) {
                // something nasty happed so retry
                tries++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // something even worse happened -> end
                running = false;
            }
        }

        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        running = false;
        wrappedTask.stop();
    }
}
```

Finally we need somthing to run our tasks...

```
public class TaskRunner implements Runnable {
    private Thread thread;
    private Task task;
    private boolean running = false;

    public TaskRunner(Task task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        if (thread != null) {
            return;
        }

        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        running = true;

        if (task != null) {
            try {
                task.work();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // log your exception
            }
        }

        thread = null;
        running = false;
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (running) {
            if (task != null) {
                task.stop();
            }
            if (thread != null) {
                thread.interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now we have all we need to is to set up a TaskRunner and start it:

```
WorkTask workTask = new WorkTask();
TaskRunner runner = new TaskRunner(new RetryingTaskWrapper(workTask, 5));
runner.start();
```

If you want to run your `WorkTask` only once without retrying that is also possible:

```
WorkTask workTask = new WorkTask();
TaskRunner runner = new TaskRunner(workTask);
runner.start();
```

If you wanted to you could even run your `WorkTask` in an infinite loop without having to change your `WorkTask` itself. All you need is to create another Wrapper

```
public class InfiniteLoopTaskWrapper implements Task {
    private Task wrappedTask;
    private boolean running = false;

    public InfiniteLoopTaskWrapper(Task wrappedTask) {
        this.wrappedTask = wrappedTask;
    }

    @Override
    public void work() {
        running = true;

        while (running) {
            try {
                wrappedTask.work();
            } catch (SomethingNastyHappenedException e) {
                // log that something nasty happened
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // something even worse happened -> end
                running = false;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        running = false;
        wrappedTask.stop();
    }

}
```

and run it...

```
WorkTask workTask = new WorkTask();
TaskRunner runner = new TaskRunner(new InfiniteLoopTaskWrapper(workTask));
runner.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

> If something nasty happens within the tasks, the parent that spawned it is protected

So I guess you have 3 options.

1. is to run the task in another process.  See something like [Get Java Runtime Process running in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711040/get-java-runtime-process-running-in-background).  I don't know of a framework that would help with this.  There aren't too many lines of code this framework would be saving you.
2. Run in another thread on the same JVM.  See below.
3. Run in another process on another server.  You are going to have to write the client/server or use a web framework or [RMI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html) to do the remoting.  I don't know of any framework that will do this for you automatically.

In terms of running it in the same JVM, I'd not use a framework at all.  I'd just run the task in a loop with proper exception handling:

```
for (int i = 0; i < retries; i++) {
   try {
      doTask();
   } catch (Throwable t) {
      // log the throwable here
   }
}
```

Seems like a framework would just be too complicated.  If the task runs out of memory then running it in another thread would not help and you will have to spawn another process to handle the task.

If you needed it to run in the background then @assyliaas' initial answer about using thread-pool is the right way to go.

Comment: Indeed - I got carried away by the title!

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue around protection.  What is the Thread goes OOM?

Comment: Np dude.  You are spot on if he needs it to run in the background @assylias.

Comment: @imrichardcole You should amend your question to make your goal clearer and explain what solutions you have considered that don't work for you.

Comment: If the thread goes OOM, then the whole JVM is going to be affected @imrichardcole.  Putting it in another thread won't help.  If you need to spawn another process then I guess you could exec it.

Comment: I didn't commit to thread or process in my original question.  I was also clear about "If something nasty happens within the tasks, the parent that spawned it is protected"